# Is there a way to get windows update information from linux?

Tags: linux, windows-update

I'm a Linux admin and do most of my administration from a Linux host.  I maintain my Linux patches with a script that goes out and queries Linux hosts, and gets uptime, last patch date and a number of patches to be applied.  I'm looking to do the same thing from windows if possible.

I've looked into WMIC for Linux(http://www.aldeid.com/wiki/wmic-linux) but from what I've seen it doesn't support the command set necessary to get the windows update information, such as found here:

http://pario.no/2011/06/19/list-installed-windows-updates-using-wmic/

While it would be great to eventually initiate updates from linux, at this point I'm just looking to get this information.  The main reason for doing it this way, is centralized administration and report gathering.

Comment: I have a vbs script that reports back available updates to my linux monitoring system.  Can be run as scheduled task or through winexe.  Will post it for you when I get back to my PC.

Answer (score 2):

You want the output of `wmic qfe get`.

I'd suggest using `winexe` or `salt` to bridge the gap:

```
$ sudo salt 'win7-salt' cmd.run 'wmic qfe get' | head -n8
win7-salt:
 Caption                                        CSName     Description      FixComments  HotFixID   InstallDate  InstalledBy              InstalledOn  Name  ServicePackInEffect  Status  
 http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=133041  WIN7-SALT  Update                        KB2849697               NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM      3/25/2014                                       
 http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=133041  WIN7-SALT  Update                        KB2849696               NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM      3/25/2014                                       
 http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=133041  WIN7-SALT  Update                        KB2841134               NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM      3/25/2014                                       
 http://support.microsoft.com/                  WIN7-SALT  Update                        KB2670838               WIN7-SALT\netdirect      11/14/2013                                      
 http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=2830477     WIN7-SALT  Update                        KB2830477               WIN7-SALT\netdirect      11/14/2013                                      
 http://support.microsoft.com/                  WIN7-SALT  Update                        KB2592687               WIN7-SALT\netdirect      11/14/2013
```

Comment: This shows installed updates. How do you show _available_ updates?

Comment: I've got no idea - I run Linux :)